# I'm trying to send esc/pos data to a VKP80II printer in C# through usb

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send a string data to my vkp80ii printer, I did this with a raw binary file and it printed but when I try to use string it doesn't do anything.

```
class VKP80II_Driver
{
    
    static USBH_Printer printer;
    static AutoResetEvent printerConnected = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Subscribe to USBH event.
        USBHostController.DeviceConnectedEvent += DeviceConnectedEvent;

        // wait for printer to be connectoed.
        printerConnected.WaitOne();
   
        // Get file to print
        //byte[] buffer = Resources.GetBytes(Resources.BinaryResources.beep);
        byte[] buffer = StrToByteArray("$0AHello World");

        // Printing can take a long time, give it a 5 seconds timeout here
        printer.SendData(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 5000);

        // Sleep forever
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    // Is printer connected event
    static void DeviceConnectedEvent(USBH_Device device)
    {
        if (device.TYPE == USBH_DeviceType.Printer)
        {
            printer = new USBH_Printer(device);
            printerConnected.Set();
        }
    }

    // Parse string object to byte array
    static byte [] StrToByteArray(string str)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

answer to the question

is i had to send real bytes to to printer

example:

```
byte[]  newByte = new bytes [] {0x0A};

printer.SendData(newByte, 0, buffer.Length, 5000);
```

Comment: If you meant this answer to be the solution to your initial question, make sure to accept it. That make the whole thing more obvious and marks your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

When I need such a functionality I couldn't find any library related to that.
So I decided to make one.

[ESC-POS-USB-NET](https://github.com/mtmsuhail/ESC-POS-USB-NET) is a free and open source .NET (C#) Implementation of the Epson ESC/POS Printing using USB Device Driver.

This library is available Open Source @ MIT license.

You can install from [Nuget Packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ESC-POS-USB-NET/)

follow the steps below:

⏳ Installation
Install Strapi with this Quickstart command to create a project instantly:

(Use nuget package manager to install (recommended))

```
Install-Package ESC-POS-USB-NET
```

or

(Use .Net Cli to install)

```
dotnet add package ESC-POS-USB-NET
```

This command install ESC-POS-USB-NET with your project.

Enjoy

❤️ Example Using C#
Import ESC_POS_USB_NET Printer Class:

```
using ESC_POS_USB_NET.Printer;
```

You can find printer name from (Windows): Control Panel->Hardware and Sound->Devices and Printers-> Your Printer's Name

Test Print:

```
Printer printer = new Printer("Printer Name");
printer.TestPrinter();
printer.FullPaperCut();
printer.PrintDocument();
```

Print Image:

```
Printer printer = new Printer("Printer Name");
Bitmap image =new Bitmap ( Bitmap.FromFile("Icon.bmp"));
printer.Image(image);
printer.FullPaperCut();
printer.PrintDocument();
```

Print Barcodes:

```
Printer printer = new Printer("Printer Name");
printer.Append("Code 128");
printer.Code128("123456789");
printer.Separator();
printer.Append("Code39");
printer.Code39("123456789");
printer.Separator();
printer.Append("Ean13");
printer.Ean13("1234567891231");
printer.FullPaperCut();
printer.PrintDocument();
```

Open Drawer:

```
Printer printer = new Printer("Printer Name");
printer.OpenDrawer();
printer.PrintDocument();
```

Typography Test:

```
Printer printer = new Printer("Printer Name");
printer.Append("NORMAL - 48 COLUMNS");
printer.Append("1...5...10...15...20...25...30...35...40...45.48");
printer.Separator();
printer.Append("Text Normal");
printer.BoldMode("Bold Text");
printer.UnderlineMode("Underlined text");
printer.Separator();
printer.ExpandedMode(PrinterModeState.On);
printer.Append("Expanded - 23 COLUMNS");
printer.Append("1...5...10...15...20..23");
printer.ExpandedMode(PrinterModeState.Off);
printer.Separator();
printer.CondensedMode(PrinterModeState.On);
printer.Append("Condensed - 64 COLUMNS");
printer.Append("1...5...10...15...20...25...30...35...40...45...50...55...60..64");
printer.CondensedMode(PrinterModeState.Off);
printer.Separator();
printer.DoubleWidth2();
printer.Append("Font Width 2");
printer.DoubleWidth3();
printer.Append("Font Width 3");
printer.NormalWidth();
printer.Append("Normal width");
printer.Separator();
printer.AlignRight();
printer.Append("Right aligned text");
printer.AlignCenter();
printer.Append("Center-aligned text");
printer.AlignLeft();
printer.Append("Left aligned text");
printer.Separator();
printer.Font("Font A", Fonts.FontA);
printer.Font("Font B", Fonts.FontB);
printer.Font("Font C", Fonts.FontC);
printer.Font("Font D", Fonts.FontD);
printer.Font("Font E", Fonts.FontE);
printer.Font("Font Special A", Fonts.SpecialFontA);
printer.Font("Font Special B", Fonts.SpecialFontB);
printer.Separator();
printer.InitializePrint();
printer.SetLineHeight(24);
printer.Append("This is first line with line height of 30 dots");
printer.SetLineHeight(40);
printer.Append("This is second line with line height of 24 dots");
printer.Append("This is third line with line height of 40 dots");
printer.NewLines(3);
printer.Append("End of Test :)");
printer.Separator();
printer.FullPaperCut();
printer.PrintDocument();
```

Features:

- **Alignment**: Left, Right and Center alignment.
- **BarCode**: Code128, Code39, Ean13 barcodes are supported.
- **Drawer**: Drawer Open facility.
- **Font Mode**: Supported Bold, Underline, Expanded, Condensed modes.
- **Change Font**: Change font to device specified FontA, FontB, FontC, FontD, FontE, SpecialFontA and SpecialFontB.
- **Font Width**: Supported Normal, DoubleWidth2 and DoubleWidth3.
- **Image**: Print BMP Image.
- **Paper Cut**: Cut paper with Full & Partial Cut.
- **QrCode**: Support 2D barcode (QrCode).